# Trying to update a certain column in the last record in sqlite in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a db that is structred as such

```
uid | username | password |     email   | cur_level
1     default      abc123   me@email.com    0
```

In my game after you complete a level in the main activity I run a method called `increase_current_level()`
    value++;
    test_db.open();
    test_db.updateLevel(value);
    cur_level = value;
    test_db.close();

So that seems to work with no problems but when `test_db.updateLevel(value)` is run, that when the program crashes.

In my DBHelper the code for update level is as follows.

```
public boolean updateLevel(String level) {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();

        args.put(KEY_CUR_LEVEL, level);
        return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "="
                + "WHERE id=(SELECT max(id) FROM DATABASE_TABLE)", null) > 0;

    }
```

My log cat error seems to be:

```
10-17 17:36:10.833: E/AndroidRuntime(1815): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "WHERE": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE test SET cur_level=? WHERE _id=WHERE id=(SELECT max(id) FROM DATABASE_TABLE)
```

I'm very new to SQLite so, it's kind of intimidating, but I hope someone sees a very obvious flaw. Thanks

### Update 1:

My updated code:

```
public boolean updateLevel(String level) {
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();

    args.put(KEY_CUR_LEVEL, level);
    return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + " = (SELECT max(id) FROM DATABASE_TABLE",
            null) > 0;

}
```

Updated error msg:

```
10-17 18:26:50.804: E/AndroidRuntime(3684): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "DATABASE_TABLE": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE test SET cur_level=? WHERE _id = (SELECT max(id) FROM DATABASE_TABLE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of `mDb.update` is

```
update(table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)
```

Let's assume that `KEY_ROWID = "id"`

For your `whereClause`, you're literally passing

```
"id = WHERE id = (SELECT max(id) FROM DATABASE_TABLE"
```

which is not valid SQL.

You don't seem to need "`id =`". Just start your `WHERE` clause with "`WHERE id=`"

However, your question implies that you have only one record in the DB. Why use a DB for one record? And if you have more than one record in it, you should use a `WHERE` clause that searches on something unique, rather than using `SELECT max(id)`.

The bottom line is that you need to improve your knowledge of SQL.

Comment: Well, I need some sort of persistent storage. I know android has sharedpreferences, but is that really the way to go if I only need one record? Even though the record may have a "ton" of "columns"?

Comment: Didn't get an answer back... but I did end up using sharedprefs in this case.

Comment: Using a database instead of sharedprefs would make it easy to add support for multiple players on the same device.  My kids play games on my phone all the time.

Answer (score 1):

From your code, your WHERE clause is probably malformed. Shouldn't it be

```
"WHERE id=(SELECT max(id) FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE
```

instead of

```
"WHERE id=(SELECT max(id) FROM DATABASE_TABLE)"
```

?

Answer (score 0):

The `update` function already puts a `WHERE` into the query, and you have duplicated the column name (`KEY_ROWID` and `"id"`). Use:

```
mDb.update(..., KEY_ROWID + "= (SELECT ...)");
```

Answer (score 0):

If your table only has one row then you don't need a WHERE clause.  The following statement should update all rows in your table.  If only one record exists this will solve your problem.

return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, null, null) > 0;

If more than one row exists you will need to know the uid of the row you want to update prior to calling the update function. In which case it would look like this...

String dbID = "the unique id of the row you want to update";

return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, "id=?", new String[]{dbID}) > 0;

Hope this helps.